# How to read Android build.gradle from Command Line or Ruby

Tags: android, ruby, bash, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to read the values in an android build.gradle file from the terminal on a Mac/Linux computer.

I can do this simply via a terminal or ruby.

I would like to be able to print out the versionCode and versionNumber via the terminal.

It would also be nice to write the versionCode and versionNumber, but reading would be enough for now.

I tried to lookup how to convert a gradle to json or another format, but think I am just missing a gradle command that would allow me to access the fields/properties inside a build.gradle file.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything akin to what you are seeking. Instead, define your `versionCode` and `versionName` in `gradle.properties` (there are Ruby gems for reading `.properties` files). Values defined in `gradle.properties` show up as global values in `build.gradle`, so you can assign those values in the `android` closure.